# How to fix the issue for TypeError: d3Legend is not a function in d3 latest version?

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vuetifyjs3

```
// LEGEND - built using Susie Lu's d3.svg.legend package
            const pieData = pie(this.dataset);

            const legendScale = d3
                .scaleOrdinal()
                .domain(pieData.map((d) => d.data.name))
                .range(d3.schemeTableau10);

            // see https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#symbols for information about d3 symbol shapes
            var legendOrdinal = d3Legend.legendColor().shape('path', d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolSquare).size(60)()).shapePadding(20).orient('vertical').scale(legendScale);

            svg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(420,20)').call(legendOrdinal);

            return svg.node();
```

> The above code is where I am trying to pass colors to the lables for Donut chart. Its throws error saying not defined.